# Accessing URL parameter from context_processor

Tags: django

Let's say we have the following URL:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),
)
```

I want to create my own context_processing which will process actions based on the  parameter. My issue here, is that I really don't know how to access the  parameter...

It is easy to access other GET parameter but for the one embedded in the URL i'm quite stuck.

```
def year_processor(request):
    # How do i access year from the request object???
    do_some_stuff(year)
    return result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try [`django.core.urlresolvers.resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#django.core.urlresolvers.resolve) where you can find more information (eg. `url_name`) about url that being processed:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

def year_processor(request):
    func, args, kwargs = resolve(request.path)

    if 'year' in kwargs:
        do_some_stuff(kwargs['year'])
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`request.resolver_match`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match), this should have what you need:

```
request.resolver_match.kwargs["year"]
```